# Gatling: Executor not accepting task when polling

Tags: kotlin, gatling

I have a gatling scenario in which I need to poll a specific endpoint for the duration of the test. However when polling the request it results in an and illegal state exception with the error `executor not accepting task` when polling.

I've had a look at the docs [here](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/polling/), but Im not sure where I'm going wrong.

The snippet looks like this:

```
        .exec(
            poll()
                .every(5)
                .exec(http("getWingboard")
                .get(WingboardEnpoints.Wingboard)
                .headers(Config.header)
                .check(status().`is`(200))
            ))
```

Errors look like this:

```
 [gatling-1-2] DEBUG i.g.h.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient - Failed to connect to remoteAddress=xxxx/108.156.28.72:443 from localAddress=null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task
        at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:61)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:194)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:162)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:148)
        at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.openNewChannelRec(DefaultHttpClient.java:809)
        at io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient.lambda$openNewChannelRec$12(DefaultHttpClient.java:843)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.doClose(AbstractNioChannel.java:502)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doClose(NioSocketChannel.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:754)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:731)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:620)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:772)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:529)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Im using Gatling gradle plugin v3.7.4 with Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

polling is a background task that only lasts as long as the virtual user is performing its main scenario. I suspect your users don't perform anything else than the polling.

Otherwise, please provide a full reproducer.

Comment: Yep that will be it. Thanks for the quick answer